# How to test event handlers Using enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

How do we test the click handlers using shallow render using enzyme

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      message
    } = this.props
    return <Alert key={message.id} bsStyle={message.state} onDismiss={()=>this.handleAlertDismiss(message.id)}>{message.text}</Alert>
  }
  handleAlertDismiss = (id) = > {
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

how do we test the `onDismiss` function that was added to the `Alert` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the component and call the dismiss function like this.

```
const log = jest.fn();
global.console = {log}
example = shallow(<Example message={{id: 'test'}}/>); 
example.props('onDismiss')() //just find the dismiss prop and call the function
expect(log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
```

The problem with your example is that there is nothing real to test. To make it work with your `console.log` example I mock `console.log` with a spy, that can be tested to check it was called with the correct parameter.

Comment: yeah I actually wasnot sure how i would calling onDismiss , if it was like    <Alert key={message.id} bsStyle={message.state} onDismiss={this.handleAlertDismiss}>{message.text}</Alert> instead of a callback in the render method , i would have tested wrapper.instance().handleAlertDismissed . My intention was not ablout console.log .sorry if it was mis leading

Comment: Ok, but is your question answered? Normally you just search for your component find the prop and call it. You could also use `simulate` which does mostly the same. http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html